# Call buttons are not working in Web App but have not problem in browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ios

Someone has created an App for my website (converted my website to an android and iOS app), but now the call buttons and Anchor tags are not working on the App, however they do not have any problem when my website open in browsers like Google chrome or fire fox browsers? could someone please tell me where is the issue?

```
<a href="tel:+964__CUSTOMER_TEL__" style="width:35%; float: right; background:#ff9933">
    <i class='fas fa-phone' style='font-size:16px'></i>
    __CUSTOMER_TEL__
</a>
```

Comment: If it's an app based on html/css/js it might be useful to mention the framework used to make that into a native app.

Comment: I have already created an website then I asked someone to convert my website to App, for my website I have not used any framework, it is written by PHP

Comment: Does the display a wkwebview ?

Comment: sorry Ptit Xav, I did not get your question? what do you mean by 'wkwebview'?

Comment: To display a website in a mobile app, some technology has to be used. Either the native app is just a simple webbrowser window displaying your website (web view ), or some framework has been used to convert the code to some hybrid native app.